# PHP Mysqli Delete from DB

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-delete

So I thought this would be a simple query to just delete rows that didn't have any data stored under certain columns, but for some reason my query is returning that zero rows have been deleted, I checked the table and they are still there.

What I want to do is delete from my `gps_routes` table where the `route_lat` and `route_long` do not contain a location (empty).

I have checked my to make sure I have delete permissions enabled as well.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gps_routes";
$result = $link->query($sql);
$rowCount = $result->num_rows; $rows_deleted = 0; $delete_row = false;

if ($rowCount > 0)
{

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 {
      $user = $row['user_email'];
      $id = $row['route_id'];
      $lat = $row['route_lat'];
      $lng = $row['route_long'];

      if (empty($lat) || empty($lng)){
        $delete_row = true;
      }

      if (ctype_space($lat) || strlen(trim($lat)) == 0){
        $delete_row = true;
      }

      if ($lat == '' || $lat == ""){
        $delete_row = true;
      }

      if ($delete_row){
        $rows_deleted++;
        mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM gps_routes WHERE user_email = '$user' AND route_id = '$id'");
     }
  }
     echo "Routes deleted: $rows_deleted";
}
```

Comment: "_What I want to do is delete from my gps_routes table where the route_lat and route_long do not contain a location (empty)."_ Your code says you want to delete from your `gps_routes` where the user's email and route_id equal specific values. Have you tried updating your query to use `$lat` and `$long` instead?

Comment: @kerbholz if you look at the code I am checking to see if the column is empty and if so deleting it for that specific user.

Comment: Ok, any reason why you select _all_ gps_routes and loop through them instead of just getting all `gps_routes WHERE route_lat IS NULL AND route_long IS NULL`? Or better yet, just `DELETE FROM gps_routes WHERE route_lat IS NULL AND route_long IS NULL`?

Comment: You need to add some debug information my friend. Right below where you define the `$user` `$id` etc variables, maybe issue some `var_dump()`s, e.g. `var_dump($user, $lat, $lng);` and see what the actual values of the fields are.

Comment: @kerbholz yeah cause if it is null and deleted then I have to update each users account with how many trips they have done.

Comment: What? Do you update the count of routes for a user every time a user adds/removes a route? You could just "count" all `gps_routes` for a certain user in sql.

Answer (score 3):

From your code is suggest that you just want to go through your DB and check to see if the lat and long are empty.  If they are then delete them.

Sounds like you can just use this query to get the job done.

```
mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM gps_routes WHERE (route_lat = '' OR route_lat IS NULL) OR (route_long = '' OR  route_long IS NULL)");
```

This is how I would do it based off the code you have provided:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM gps_routes WHERE (route_lat = '' OR route_lat IS NULL) OR (route_long = '' OR  route_long IS NULL)";
$result = $link->query($query);

echo 'Routes deleted: ' . $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: I don't even understand why contributor had to loop his delete there by wasting so much resource deleting each row one at a time +1

Comment: @Bobby Axe It's learning..  I'm sure I still make mistakes that someone better than me would look at and say something similar.

Comment: Well that's true. Am not perfect either looking back at some of my old code i wonder who wrote that stuff.